# Initializing Visual Composer upon Ajax content load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, visual-composer

Basic Structure below, have an ajax script that replaces the div inner-content and updates the menu, pushes history states, fade in/out contents ect..

The inner-content contains a foundation grid row and content of wordpress editor lives inside that container.

Now here is the issue... when using any Visual composer function that requires javascript triggers, Full width Span, slider, animations nothing gets loaded again when my ajax function triggers a content replace.

Here is part of my code that loads after ajax have got the content.

```
// Update the content
$content.stop(true,true);
//$("[data-vc-grid-settings]").vcGrid();
$('#content').foundation();
$content.html(contentHtml).ajaxify().css('opacity',100).show(); /* you could fade in here if you'd like */

// Update the title
document.title = $data.find('.document-title:first').text();
```

I thought `.vcGrid()` was the right init, but got the not defined console error.
Where can I find docs related to re-initializing the visual composer elements?

```
<html>
<header>
Meta Content
</header>
<div off-canvus>
   <menu></menu>
   <div content>
      <div inner-content>

      </div>
   </div>
   <footer>
   </footer>
   <scripts>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the data I needed after digging through visual composer's javascript, added a resize action for window which triggers the visual composer's grid to work correctly.

```
$content.stop(true,true);
window.vc_js();
window.resize();
$('#content').foundation();
$content.html(contentHtml).ajaxify().css('opacity',100).show(); /* you could fade in here if you'd like */

// Update the title
document.title = $data.find('.document-title:first').text();
try {
    document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = document.title.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;').replace(' & ',' &amp; ');
}
catch ( Exception ) { }
```

Comment: I know this is late to ask, but I have the same problem and your code is not working for me.
I get error window.resize() is not a function.
also tried jQuery("[data-vc-grid-settings]").vcGrid(); and gives vcGrid is not a function

Comment: @buxbeatz you are loading your code before other resources are loaded.

Answer (score 3):

to add some custom javascript logic **after** Visual composer grid has been loaded do it like this:

```
$(window).bind( 'grid:items:added', function(){ 
  // add some logic here
});
```

for detailes look at this question => [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436986/reload-visual-composer-grid-after-ajax-call/48378966#48378966)